# Read two files simultaneously and create one from them

Tags: bash, curl

I am new to Bash scripting, but do understand most of the basics. My scenario is as follows:

I have a server from which I get a load of data via cURL. This is parsed properly (XML format) and from these results I then extract the data I want. The cURL statement writes its output to a file called `temp-rec-schedule.txt`. The below code is what I use to get the values I want to use in further calculation.

```
MP=`cat temp-rec-schedule.txt | grep "<ns3:mediapackage" | awk -F' ' '{print $3}' | cut -d '=' -f 2 | awk -F\" '{print $(NF-1)}'`
REC_TIME=`cat temp-rec-schedule.txt | grep "<ns3:mediapackage" | awk -F' ' '{print $2}' | cut -d '=' -f 2 | awk -F\" '{print $(NF-1)}'`
```

So this all still work perfectly. The output of the above code is respectively (if written to two separate files):

MP output:

```
    b1706f0d-2cf1-4fd6-ab60-ae4d08608f1f
    fd578fcc-342c-4f6c-986a-794ccb1abd0c
    ce9f40e9-8e2c-4654-ba1c-7f79d35a69fd
    c31a2354-6f4b-4bfe-b51e-2bac80889897
    df342d88-c660-490e-9da6-9c91a7966536
    49083f88-4264-4629-80fb-fae480d0bb25
    946121c7-4948-4254-9cb5-2457e1b99685
    f7bd0cad-e8f5-4e3d-a219-650d07a4bb34
```

REC_TIME output:

```
    2014-09-15T07:30:00Z
    2014-09-19T08:58:00Z
    2014-09-22T07:30:00Z
    2014-10-13T07:30:00Z
    2014-10-17T08:58:00Z
    2014-10-20T07:30:00Z
    2014-10-22T13:28:00Z
    2014-10-27T07:30:00Z
```

What I want to do now is create a file where `line1` from `file1` is appended with `line1` from `file2`. i.e. :

```
    b1706f0d-2cf1-4fd6-ab60-ae4d08608f1f 2014-09-15T07:30:00Z
    fd578fcc-342c-4f6c-986a-794ccb1abd0c 2014-09-19T08:58:00Z
```

and so on.

I am not really familiar with Perl, but do know a little bit about Bash, so if it is possible, I would like to do this in Bash.

Further, from here, I want to compare two files that contain the same MP variable, but have two different TIME values assigned: subtract the one value from the other, and calculate the amount of hours that have passed between.  This is all to calculate the amount of hours that have passed between publishing a video on our system, and the start time of the recording. Basically:

File1's output: `b1706f0d-2cf1-4fd6-ab60-ae4d08608f1f 2014-09-15T07:30:00Z`
File2's output: `b1706f0d-2cf1-4fd6-ab60-ae4d08608f1f 2014-09-15T09:30:00Z`

The output of my script should yield a value of `2 hours`.

How can I do this with Bash?

Comment: You should really focus on one question at a time.

Comment: There is rarely a need to pipe `grep` into `awk`, nor to use `cat`.  `cat foo | grep bar | awk '{...}'` is the same as `awk '/bar/{...} foo'`

Comment: Agreed with both previous comments. It would be more useful if you showed a sample of the original file, as it may be easier to do this in one step.

Comment: Understood about 1 question at a time. I just thought showing where I was heading might help in understanding why exactly I did what I have done so far.

Comment: It should be mentioned also that using any of these tools to parse XML is the wrong idea and that something like XSLT is the right idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably better off just using `awk` for the whole thing.  Something like:

```
awk '/<ns3:medipacakge/{gsub("\"",""); 
    split($3,mp,"="); 
    split($2,rt,"="); print mp[2],rt[2]}'  temp-rec-schedule.txt
```

Comment: Thank you for this, but being new to this, I'm not totally sure what all of this does? So you will have to give me some time to figure out exactly how all of this works, and get back to you. Thanks again!

Comment: The `/.../` bit is a pattern match to select only lines that match that pattern. `gsub` replaces parts of the string that match its first argument with its second argument; in this case dropping double quotes from the line (default gsub string to operate on is the current line). `split` splits the line into the array (second argument) on the pattern in the third argument. Then it just prints out the second field in each of those arrays next to one another.

Comment: @Etan Reisner, thanks, but I think I am MUCH more stupid than originally thought. An example of the file I'm reading from (temp-rec-schedule.txt) is:
<ns3:mediapackage start="2014-09-15T07:30:00Z" id="b1706f0d-2cf1-4fd6-ab60-ae4d08608f1f" duration="6000000">

I'm looking for the values of start="xyz" AND id="abc" to be printed as explained in the original post. I think the gsub part is throwing me, as I understood it searches for \ and replaces it with , . Is that true? Sorry, eager to learn but may portray as very stupid. Maybe quite rightly so :-)

Comment: @BashNewbie The arguments to `gsub` here are `"\""` and `""`. A string containing an escaped double quote (since `"""` wouldn't parse correctly) and an empty string.

Comment: Thank you!  Got this working! Will mark this as the solution. Fixed one or two typos which threw me as well, but thank you @William Pursell, you helped me a lot! Thank you also Etan Reisner

Answer (score 0):

The answer to the first question is to write the output to two different files and then use `paste`.

```
grep "<ns3:mediapackage" temp-rec-schedule.txt | awk -F' ' '{print $3}' | cut -d '=' -f 2 | awk -F\" '{print $(NF-1)}' > MP_out.txt
grep "<ns3:mediapackage" temp-rec-schedule.txt | awk -F' ' '{print $2}' | cut -d '=' -f 2 | awk -F\" '{print $(NF-1)}' > REC_out.txt
paste MP_out.txt REC_out.txt
```

That being said (and as @WilliamPursell says in his comment on the OP) there is never a reason to string this series of commands together since awk can do all the things you are doing there with **significantly** less overhead and more flexibility.

Comment: Are you honestly recommending `grep | awk | cut | awk` twice on the same file, followed by `paste`?! Even without seeing the exact format, this can be improved a lot.

Comment: @TomFenech No, I'm suggesting that given his existing commands adding `paste` is the solution. Also that using a single awk is likely better (though I suppose I could strengthen the wording of that).